# iOS Shortcuts: can’t append open file

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I have a simple note-taking iOS shortcut that asks for text input and then appends it, formatted, to a long running note file.

The problem is that if an application has that file open, Shortcuts won’t append the file. Is there a way to overcome this?

I have a safety mechanism in place that also copies the text to clipboard so I don’t lose it, but I’d rather not needing this.

Shortcuts doesn’t allow closing apps but I could have the Shortcut first open a different file in every app that could open the notes file. This would slow the Shortcut down whenever those apps aren’t open, but this is my best solution so far.